# Minecraft will not launch!!! Please Help!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Minecraft has always previously worked and now all of a sudden it says. Java SE Binary has stopped working after pressing launch. Minecraft Version : 1.11.2, also happens with all other versions. It is also using the new launcher.

Here is Error.

```
3724 debugs 16 infos 1 warning,
18:19:32    launcher    Preparing to launch minecraft client for 1.11.2
,18:19:32   launcher    Checking installations.
,18:19:32   launcher    Minecraft client 1.11.2 is ready to start.
,18:19:32   launcher    Starting!
,18:19:32   launcher    Using default game log configuration client-1.7.xml (outputs XML)
,18:19:33   bes Setting user: LordSarcasm
,18:19:34   beu Skipping bad option: lastServer:
,18:19:34   bes LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
,18:19:35   cae Reloading ResourceManager: Default
,18:19:36   ccq Starting up SoundSystem...
, 18:19:36  ccq Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
, 18:19:36  ccq (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
, 18:19:37  ccq OpenAL initialized.
, 18:19:37  ccq Sound engine started
, 18:19:41  byy Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
, 18:19:58  launcher    Process closed with exit code -1073740791
, 18:19:58  launcher
```

Thankyou for any help.

Answer (score 0):

## This is a graphics driver error and can be fixed

This is the error:

```
Process closed with exit code -1073740791
```

Some googling uncovered that this is a [known error caused by a faulty version 378.57 GeForce graphics driver](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-112780).

According to that close bug report, to fix it before the next full driver is released, you have to install a [hotfix for your graphics driver](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4378/) from the video card vendor. This is what the vendor (NVidia) has to say about the hotfix:

> This is GeForce Hot Fix driver version 378.57 that addresses the following:
>
> - Fixed crash in Minecraft and some other Java-based titles
> - Resolved 'Debug Mode' as default option on Pascal based GPUs

This will probably be fixed in the next official GeForce driver, so it's a temporary problem and this fix will not work for future crashes with this error.